# What's a good access module for a state-level organization?

Tags: users

I'm setting up a new website for the Maine Grand Chapter of the Order of the Eastern Star. My goal is to allow each chapter to access their own chapter's node (and nobody else's) and modify the content (annual updates to officers, calendars, etc.) and hopefully also to maintain a group calendar (modules for this yet to be chosen). So, my question at the moment is what the best node access module to use for this purpose is. I'm using D7.20. [Flexi access](http://drupal.org/project/flexiaccess) looks interesting, but there are so many to choose from...

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module. This will allow you to designate individual users as responsible for the each group, and will allow each chapter to post content to their own chapter (kind of a mini web page for each chapter).

You can see an example of this format [here](http://www.frontenacmasons.com).

Comment: That looks like overkill for my purposes, but thanks. :-)

Comment: It is not overkill if you are looking at a group calendar. Have a look at [D7 Organic Group Calendars](http://drupal.org/node/1268156).

Comment: Ah, I see. That's very interesting -- I'll need to keep this in mind going forward.